# MySql Table Order by values with Split string

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

guide if it is possible to the solution.

[image]

I need table result as follows

```
 RAJ1  RAJ2  ARUN  MUTHU
 -----------------------
 86     74    45   null
 74     86    45   null
 null   74    45    86
```

I don't know where to start to implement this by on procedure or by normal query.

Comment: Union each column into one long list, splitting name, value into 2 columns then pivot on name.  performance will be slow due to the string manipulation but that's what happens when we have denormalized data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(
    IF(LEFT(subj1,4)='RAJ1', SUBSTRING(subj1,6), NULL),
    IF(LEFT(subj2,4)='RAJ1', SUBSTRING(subj2,6), NULL),
    IF(LEFT(subj3,4)='RAJ1', SUBSTRING(subj3,6), NULL)) as RAJ1,
  COALESCE(
    IF(LEFT(subj1,4)='RAJ2', SUBSTRING(subj1,6), NULL),
    IF(LEFT(subj2,4)='RAJ2', SUBSTRING(subj2,6), NULL),
    IF(LEFT(subj3,4)='RAJ2', SUBSTRING(subj3,6), NULL)) as RAJ2,
  COALESCE(
    IF(LEFT(subj1,4)='ARUN', SUBSTRING(subj1,6), NULL),
    IF(LEFT(subj2,4)='ARUN', SUBSTRING(subj2,6), NULL),
    IF(LEFT(subj3,4)='ARUN', SUBSTRING(subj3,6), NULL)) as ARUN,
  COALESCE(
    IF(LEFT(subj1,5)='MUTHU', SUBSTRING(subj1,7), NULL),
    IF(LEFT(subj2,5)='MUTHU', SUBSTRING(subj2,7), NULL),
    IF(LEFT(subj3,5)='MUTHU', SUBSTRING(subj3,7), NULL)) as MUTHU
FROM thetable;
```